# How to identify start transition on SDA for I2C?

Tags: i2c

I am trying to understand serial protocols, I started with I2C. A high to low transition on SDA before positive edge of SCL indicates start of transaction. But there can be several high to low transitions on SDC, how does receiver know which transition is the "start" indicator?

Comment: Just read up on this https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/i2c/all. The "Basic" section provides the waves with SDA and SDC

Answer (score 4):

A high to low transition on SDA before positive edge of SCL does not indicate start of transaction.

Start condition is defined by high to low SDA transition while SCL is high.

There are no such transactions during bit transmissions as SDA changes while SCL is low.

For further info, refer to the actual I2C specification or any relevant  application note which explains I2C.